# Performance comparison cx_oracle vs write.format('jdbc')

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone tell me which way to insert in oracle is more performatico?

Write.format('jdbc') mode or using CX_Oracle?

In my project I came across a case where they use write.format('jdbc') to INSERT and CX_Oracle to UPDATE, so I'm thinking of changing to INSERT and UPDATE on the same CX_Oracle connection, what do you think ?

Comment: AFAIK (and i may be incorrect), it's best to use `df.write.format('jdbc')` when using pyspark and `cx_oracle` only helps with pandas dataframes. when using oracle solely (no df required), then `cx_oracle` will help you execute sql queries directly in your database without the need of reading it within the pyspark env.

Comment: I worked on a similar case recently (disclaimer: I work for Oracle), and cx_Oracle was not faster than using JDBC writes. The customer ended up using both, but cx_Oracle is for row-level inserts updates and deletes only.

Comment: At the lower level, cx_Oracle's `executeMany()` is _very_ efficient for insert or updates.  I don't know how this is accessed via spark.

Answer (score 1):

I has worked on similar usecase. Here are some takeaway from my last project.

1. `cx_oracle` is very slow compared to `write.format('jdbc')`. I was inserting 1M records and there was drastic difference b/w those two approach. `cx_oracle` even with executeMany didn't help much. I will strongly recommend to use spark JDBC.
2. Even in case of update, I ended up doing delete (SQL Query) - insert (using pyspark), because couldn't achieve update in spark and the alternative was very slow.
3. Spark does parallel writes while inserting to db too.
4. Even for read operation use spark jdbc read because spark will optimize the job and send projection and filtering at DB directly.